# Type mismatch in seemingly equal use cases

Tags: types, f#, printf

I'm creating a module to access a MySQL database. Since SQLProvider fell short in needed functionality, and since said functionality is in fact pretty simple, I decided to roll my own based on the usual ADO.NET SqlConnection.

To make using the API less clunky, I used  [Tomas Petriceks idea](http://tomasp.net/blog/dynamic-sql.aspx/) with some [slight modifications](https://gist.github.com/leflings/3df8ba4d82867ee770ab)

The following shows the central parts of problem I have

```
let internal connectionFor ta =
    let conn = new DynamicSqlConnection(connectionStringFor ta)
    conn.Open()
    conn

let executeQuery queryString parameters map ta =
    use conn = connectionFor ta
    use cmd = conn %% queryString
    List.iter (fun setter -> setter cmd) parameters
    use r = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    [| while r.Read() do yield map r |]

let getKolSkillInterests ta =
    let map r =
        {   Id = r?id
            KolId = r?kol_id
            SkillId = r?skill_id
            SkillInterestTypeId = r?skill_interests_types_id }
    executeQuery "SELECT * FROM tb_kol_skills_interests" [] map ta

let getCountryById ta i =
    let query = "SELECT * FROM tb_lu_country WHERE id = @countryId"
    let parameters = [ fun (c:DynamicSqlCommand) -> c?countryId <- i ]
    let map r =
        { Id = r?id
          Label = r?label
          RegionId = r?region
          Abbreviation = r?country_abbreviation
          RealCountry = bigintToBool r?real_country }
    executeQuery query parameters map ta
                                  ^^^ Error here
```

The `executeQuery` function works well, when used in interactive mode, **however** in the above snippet, while `getKolSkillInterests` compiles and works, the `getCountryById` function will not compile. The squiglly marks occur under the `map` parameter to `executeQuery` with the error `Type mismatch. The type PrintfFormat<'a,'b,'c','a,unit> is not compatible with the type string`

I know F# has pretty cryptic error messages at times, but I cannot grok this one.

Note, if I inline the parameters, as shown below - *it works*

```
let getCountryById ta (i:int) =
    executeQuery
        "SELECT * FROM tb_lu_country WHERE id = @countryId"
        [fun (c:DynamicSqlCommand) -> c?countryId <- i]
        (fun r ->
            { Id = r?id
              Label = r?label
              RegionId = r?region
              Abbreviation = r?country_abbreviation
              RealCountry = bigintToBool r?real_country })
        ta
```

Comment: Try annotating all function parameters with their expected concrete types until you figure out what went wrong.

Comment: @nodakai - which parameters exactly? The parameters to `executeQuery`are all inferred correctly to (string -> (DynamicSqlCommand -> unit) list -> (DynamicSqlDataReader -> 'a) -> TherapeuticArea -> 'a []). The type of `map` in `getCountryById` is (DynamicSqlDataReader -> Country). So the type mismatch, it seems, isn't really that the provided arguments is not of the correct type, but stems from something deeper, which is what I cannot figure out - less so when the "inlined" version works

Answer (score 2):

These cases are not actually "equal".

I don't exactly know what operator `%%` does, but from your error message it is clear that it expects a `PrintfFormat<...>` as second argument, and therefore, through the magic of type inference, the `queryString` parameter of your `executeQuery` function is also of type `PrintfFormat<...>`.

Now, this type `PrintfFormat<...>` is special. It is so special that the compiler itself provides a hack (of sorts) when compiling it, and that's how you can use `printf`. Try this:

```
printf "Abcd %d" 15  // Works just fine

let s = "Abcd %d"
printf s 15  // Same error as you're getting
```

Why is that? Turns out, in F#, string literals are not always of type `string`. Sometimes, depending on the context, they can be of type `PrintfFormat<...>`. If the compiler sees that the context requires `PrintfFormat<...>`, it will compile string literal as that instead of `string`. That's why the first `printf` call above works and the second one doesn't: the symbol `s` has already been inferred as `string`, and so it doesn't work as argument for `printf`, which is expected to be `PrintfFormat<...>`.

The example above is easily fixable - you just need to give the compiler a hand in figuring out your intended types:

```
let s: PrintfFormat<_,_,_,_> = "Abcd %d"
printf s 15  // Works now
```

As so your code is similarly fixable:

```
let getCountryById ta i =
    let query: PrintfFormat<_,_,_,_> = "SELECT * FROM tb_lu_country WHERE id = @countryId"
    let parameters = [ fun (c:DynamicSqlCommand) -> c?countryId <- i ]
    let map r =
        { Id = r?id
          Label = r?label
          RegionId = r?region
          Abbreviation = r?country_abbreviation
          RealCountry = bigintToBool r?real_country }
    executeQuery query parameters map ta
```

P.S. Of course, since you're not actually using the `PrintfFormat` capabilities, you may want to redesign your API so that it takes a `string`, thus making it easier for the consumer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of why printf is so powerful in F#. I've run in this earlier, so I was looking out for this. What makes you think it's clear that the `%%` operator takes a PrintfFormat<_> as a second parameter? The implementation, as linked in the post, is here: https://gist.github.com/leflings/3df8ba4d82867ee770ab

Comment: And I will admit, that even having an operator for what `%%` does is overly obscure, with no real win.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not saying there's type mismatch. F# type inference cannot type all well typed F# code without some explicit annotation because of too much deviation from classical Hindley-Milner-Damas (Also Google for "F# left to right inference".)

I see your error msg contains PrintfFormat which, I suspect, originated from MySQL binding, so I won't go into the full details.  But I'd say (s)printf of F# is complex enough that whether you gave type annotation or not might change how type inference goes.

Please recall that inlining function arguments which are themselves polymorphic is equivalent to adding some type annotations to them, because when their types are inferred, you already have the surrounding context (executeQuery in this case whose type was, as you observed, already inferred.)  Again, top-to-bottom and left-to-right inference.

This is why I'm concerned with giving more and more type annotations.

Comment: You were indeed right about the type annotations. Not that IntelliSense (or I guess, the FSharp Compiler Service) hadn't inferred the right type (which in the case of the failing example would have to be inferred from the application to `executeQuery`), but annotating the `r`parameter to the `map` function with `DynamicSqlDataReader` did indeed get rid of the error. The actual PrintfFormat error, I'm fairly certain, comes from the way F# does dynamic (the `?` operator, aka `op_Dynamic`). I'll post an answer tomorrow with the changes I made.